# Converter valor de VARIANT DATE para date

Tags: php, data, dataframe

Tenho estes dois valores onde um é a data de emissão e outro a data de entrega. Os valores são 45111.544874664 e 45111.71696559. Trata-se do tipo VARIANT DATE aonde através do site que coloquei como exemplo é possível converter os números para data e hora.

Site para exemplo:
https://planetcalc.com/7027/

Fiz pesquisas na internet e pelo menos até então não encontrei como converter este formato para data e hora em PHP.

Como faço a conversão deste formato para data e hora em PHP?

Answer (score -2):

Após perguntar aqui continuei a minha pesquisa em busca da resolução e acabei encontrando. Vou compartilhar aqui para auxiliar outro que venha encontrar o mesmo problema:

```
    $variantDate = '45111.544874664';

    $dias = floor($variantDate);
    $data = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('1899-12-30 + ' . $dias . ' days'));
```